# # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- on python3

Tags: python

I'm using Python 3.x on windows.

Should I use the `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` declaration on my files?
I have read many topics and I think the answer is no but i'm not sure.

Btw i'm writing only in english and italian.
Maybe you have to know something else but i don't know what... so ask me

Thank you

Comment: If you plan write Py2/Py3 portable code, indeed. Btw. `-*-` sequences are redundant.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[PEP 3120](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3120/) defines UTF-8 as the default source encoding for Python 3.x. If you save the file as that encoding (or as ASCII, of course) then no encoding declaration is required.

The [What's New In Python 3.0](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html) document [declares](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#index-4) its implementation.

Comment: Foreign usernames can be a problem?

Comment: @fabio foreign usernames should not be a problem while using utf-8